# SUM a column then SUBTRACT to the SUM of another column

Tags: sql-server, datagrid

I have a table that has this fields:

```
EmpID,
Code,
Amount,
TransDate,
CM,
CMDate
```

What I want to get to a datagrid, is to `SUM` all the `Amount` that has the same `Code` and `SUM` the `CM` that has the same `Code` as the `Amount` then subtract the `SUM(Amount)` to the `SUM(CM)` but if the Result IS `NULL` (e.g. there is no `CM` to SUM and Subtract to the `SUM(Amount)`) then it just have to select the `SUM(Amount)`. I came up with this statement:

```
SELECT
    TransDate, 
    Code, 
    SUM(Amount) - SUM(CM) AS 'Result'
FROM DeductionTbl
WHERE 
    (EmpID = @empID)
GROUP BY Code, TransDate
ORDER BY TransDate
```

I get the Result value if there is a `SUM(CM)` to subtract to the `SUM(Amount)` but I get the Result `NULL` value if there is no `SUM(CM)` of the same `Code`. I don't want the `NULL` value on the datagrid. If there is a `NULL` value just return the `SUM(Amount)`. Is there a way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Specially to Farhang Amary.

Comment: you are very welcome. glad to see the issue has fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `ISNULL`s:

```
SELECT
    TransDate, 
    Code, 
    isnull(SUM(isnull(Amount,0)),0) - isnull(SUM(isnull(CM,0)),0) AS 'Result'
FROM DeductionTbl
WHERE 
    (EmpID = @empID)
GROUP BY Code, TransDate
ORDER BY TransDate
```

> **NOTE:**
>
> The `SUM(ISNULL(CM,0))` may return `NULL` when running query on an
>   empty result set also it avoid the `ANSI WARNINGS` about `aggregating NULL`.
>
> And `ISNULL(SUM(CM),0)` is not regarded as nullable.

Comment: Surely the nested ISNULLs are redundant!

Comment: @JohnS, sorry but you are wrong, because `SUM(isnull(CM,0))` may be `null`. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this, The IsNull converts NULLS to zeros in this case.

```
SELECT
    TransDate, 
    Code, 
    SUM(Amount) - SUM(ISNULL(CM, 0)) AS 'Result'
FROM DeductionTbl
WHERE 
    (EmpID = @empID)
GROUP BY Code, TransDate
ORDER BY TransDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Any operation using a null value will usually result in null. You need to handle the null value as a 0. We use the ISNULL function for this.
Try this...

```
SELECT
TransDate, 
Code, 
SUM(Amount) - ISNULL(SUM(CM), 0) AS 'Result'
FROM DeductionTbl
WHERE 
(EmpID = @empID)
GROUP BY Code, TransDate
ORDER BY TransDate
```