# Calculating running balance with limit

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a small accounting app. The following function is used to get transaction of a supplier. I want get the balance after each transaction in this loop. Can some one provide me a best method.

```
public function transaction_by_id_paginated($supplier_id,$start_from,$limit) {
$sql="
SELECT *
  FROM transactions  
 WHERE tr_sup_id = $supplier_id 
 ORDER 
    BY tr_date DESC 
 LIMIT $start_from, $limit
";
$suppliers = DB::fetch($sql);
return $suppliers;          
}
```

With this function i want get a calculated balance value. I am not storing balance in DB.

Fields in `transactions` tables are

```
tr_id (Primary) int(11) 
tr_sup_id   int(11) 
bill_id int(11)     
tr_date date        
tr_type varchar(250)        
tr_bill int(250)        
tr_payment  int(250)        
tr_payment_note varchar(250)
```

i want balance which is equal to `balance = balance + tr_payment - tr_bill`

Comment: Do you need the total of `tr_payment` from the table?

Comment: No i want balance which is equal to balance = balance+ tr_payment - tr_bill

Comment: Please Specify them in the question.

Comment: And Which one is the first `balance`? Is it 0?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28162773/sum-a-column-then-subtract-to-the-sum-of-another-column Have a try with this

Comment: Yes its basically a bank like system. payment is + bill is -

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT i, @j:=@j+i FROM ints, (SELECT @j:=0) vars ORDER BY i;
+---+----------+
| i | @j:=@j+i |
+---+----------+
| 0 |        0 |
| 1 |        1 |
| 2 |        3 |
| 3 |        6 |
| 4 |       10 |
| 5 |       15 |
| 6 |       21 |
| 7 |       28 |
| 8 |       36 |
| 9 |       45 |
+---+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT i, @j:=@j+i FROM ints, (SELECT @j:=0) vars ORDER BY i LIMIT 3,6;
+---+----------+
| i | @j:=@j+i |
+---+----------+
| 3 |        3 |
| 4 |        7 |
| 5 |       12 |
| 6 |       18 |
| 7 |       25 |
| 8 |       33 |
+---+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```